# Sublime Text 3 Jade classes autocomplete

Tags: pug, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Sublime 3 used to work perfectly, but recently I've got problems with Jade and it slows down my work seriously.

What I had before. When I was writing some class name in Jade I only needed to type dot or dot and the first letter. Sublime was showing me suggestions in a popup. I could choose the class name if I used it alrealy in my document. Now it doesn't show me anything. I have to type same class names over and over and sometimes they are quite long.

I checked all packages, I tried to find plugins and no luck unfortunately. I don't know what's wrong with it and I can't figure out what package could affect the way it used to work. Many hours of Googling didn't help me. Does anyone know what could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally I've find the solution myself. Maybe it's not the best one, but at least it works. I checked Jade package repository and found out that the author renamed it from 'source.jade' to 'text.jade'. So I've added in Sublime User Settings the following line:

```
"auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "text.jade - string - comment - constant.numeroc", "characters": "."} ]
```